# mudtable and mudhidden not working in prerendering blazor wasm mode

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

Some features not working in prerendering mode. I'm using .NET 6 and mudblazor 6.0.11.

Some components such as `mudtable` and `mudhidden` do not work properly; `mudHidden` is hidden always and `mudTable` is not showing data.

I've added this code in `program.cs` in the server app:

```
services.AddMudServices(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.SnackbarConfiguration.PositionClass = Defaults.Classes.Position.BottomRight;
                configuration.SnackbarConfiguration.HideTransitionDuration = 100;
                configuration.SnackbarConfiguration.ShowTransitionDuration = 100;
                configuration.SnackbarConfiguration.VisibleStateDuration = 3000;
                configuration.SnackbarConfiguration.ShowCloseIcon = false;
            });
```

Comment: Have you injected the required css and js files for mudblazor in your `_host.cshtml` or `index.html`?

Comment: Yes,I copied all the contents of index.html to _host.razor